# Protégé querying individuals

Tags: sparql, protege, dlquery

I have a very basic question for query languages in Protégé. 
I have a class called "year", and there are 3 individuals who are members of this class as 1800, 1850 and 1900. 
I would like to set up a query for individuals in order to get individuals of that year class, but only the ones starting with 19, not 18.
Is it possible through DL Query?

Comment: No, you can't filter by entity names. DL Query is a logical query. If `year` would be a data property, then yes. To be honest, I don't understand why you have such a class, but I don't know your data at all.

Comment: You could use SPARQL for the query.

Comment: Thank you @AKSW could you pls examplify such a query in Sparql?

Comment: `SELECT ?s WHERE {?s a :year . FILTER(strstarts(str(s), '19'))}` (untested)